# Change Font Name & Size in RichTextBox While Retaining Formatting

Tags: c#, formatting, richtextbox

I've managed a solution to change a Rich Text Documents' Font (Name & Size) while retaining style (ie: bold, italic, underline). However, my solution requires two additional RTB's (both not visible). The relevant code (below) is handled via Font Name/Size dropdownlist:

```
            rtb.Font.Dispose();
            //store style info in Temp1
            _temp1.Rtf = rtb.Rtf;
            //store new font in Temp2
            _temp2.Text = rtb.Text;
            _temp2.Font = new Font(fontDropDown.Text, int.Parse(fontSizeDropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()));//replaces FONT and STYLE
            //
            _temp1.Focus();
            for (int i = 0; i < _temp1.TextLength; i++)
            {
                _temp1.Select(i, 1);
                if (_temp1.SelectionFont != null)
                {
                    _temp2.Select(i, 1);//set font to Font of temp2, style from temp1
                    _temp2.SelectionFont = new Font(_temp2.SelectionFont, _temp1.SelectionFont.Style);
                }
            }
            rtb.Rtf = _temp2.Rtf;
            //
            markAsModified();
```

I'm using two non-visible temp RTB's because I'm concerned about the possibility of "flickering". 
I'm just wondering if there's a better way to do this, WITHOUT pInvoking or InterOp.
***Also**: Since this solution makes me worry about memory/performance issues I'd like to know the likelihood of this code causing such an issue.

Comment: Make sure to use your invisible RTF Controls in using blocks. If you create much RTF Controls this is very memory expensive.

Comment: You need no extra RTB, just follow the rules: __Never__ change the Text property! __Only__ modify the SelectionXXX properties and/or the SelectedText after setting the selection via SelectionStart and SelectionLength! . Working with __raw__ RTF is a __pain__ and usually not necessary. To the right are many posts with good examples..  ===>